# Red5 server failing to start up due to java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, red5

I have recently started to learn about Red5 server. I am following this tutorial to develop a simple video chat app:  `http://tharas.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/chat-application-with-red5-and-flex/`.

I am able to create the flex client.

For the service side, I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. Then manually copied the WEB-INF folder files and the Application.java file from the source code zip given in the above tutorial page at the bottom.

After that when I am trying to start the Red5 server, it is failing with the error: `Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use.`

I searched many forums for hours to resolve this. What I could figure out is, it is possible that the server start up script is trying to create RMI registry entry in the JVM twice, which is not allowed. One forum suggested editing the /etc/hosts file. One forum suggested commenting out the rmiregistry creation in red5.properties and delete the JMX part in red5-common.xml. But nothing worked!

I have installed Red5 version 1.0 in Windows 8. I have installed the Red5 Eclipse plugin and running the server from within Eclipse.

Any help is appreciated. If you need, I can post the detailed server log.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that more than one instance of Red5 is being started or the RMI registry already exists. I suggest editing your red5/conf/red5.properties file and changing this entry to false:

```
jmx.registry.create=true
```

This should "hide" the error and allow you to continue; the real fix would be to prevent spawning multiple instances within Eclipse.