# Red5 BeanCreationException for rmiRegistry

Tags: jakarta-ee, red5, rmiregistry

I created an Red5 Application as described [here](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/red5prolive/#red5pro-live-application).
While starting red5 I receive following Exception:

```
[WARN] [0.0.0.0-startStop-1] org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rmiRegistry' defined in class path resource [red5-common.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.refresh(Red5ApplicationContext.java:36) [red5-server.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:151) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext.afterPropertiesSet(Red5ApplicationContext.java:30) [red5-server.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:383) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:558) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:303) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use
    at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable.putTarget(ObjectTable.java:186) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.exportObject(Transport.java:106) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:251) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:194) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

red5-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/red5-web.properties" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="web.context" class="org.red5.server.Context" autowire="byType" />
    <bean id="web.scope" class="org.red5.server.WebScope" init-method="register">
        <property name="server" ref="red5.server" />
        <property name="parent" ref="global.scope" />
        <property name="context" ref="web.context" />
        <property name="handler" ref="web.handler" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="${webapp.contextPath}" />
        <property name="virtualHosts" value="${webapp.virtualHosts}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="web.handler" class="com.alethia.red5.Red5App" /> <!-- singleton="true" /> -->
</beans>
```

The Red5 is an fresh installation from https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases/tag/v1.0.6-RELEASE i choosed the red5-server-1.0.6-RELEASE-server.tar.gz and installed it into /opt/red5/server1.0.6 of my Ubuntu 15.10.
default JDK is oracle 8

I hope anybody can tell me, what I heave not done yet.

[EDITS]
 There is only one instace of red5.
 There is no anti virus running. 
 java -version' output:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Make sure you only have one instance of Red5 running.

Comment: Checked - only one instance :/

Comment: Searched around and this issue is reported as being a conflict with antivirus software, host file configuration, and also non-unique computer name. Check those options. I would also make sure you're running the latest java (version 8).

Comment: You can also try this if all else fails: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25446968/127938

Comment: The host file and non-unique computer name options I'll check. As I understand your link just 'hide' the error, but does not solve it..

Comment: The link prevents the starting of an additional instance of the RMI server; its  not meant to hide anything, but to work with an already existing instance.